# Does Oracle PreparedStatement.executeUpdate() handle connection pool exhaution by throwing an instance of SQLException?

Tags: java, oracle, connection-pooling

Will Oracle `PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()` API throw an exception of type `SQLException` if the connection pool is exhausted?

My application codes (`KMDatabaseDAO.insert()`) is calling the Oracle `PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()` API, however, the method seems to only throw an `SQLException`, because existing production codes have pretty messed up the logging level, i am unable to recover the actual logs printing out.

Below is the thread dump taken.

```
"ExecuteThread: '79' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default'" daemon prio=1 tid=0x1b459f28 nid=0x5c62 runnable [1842b000..1842c228]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:979)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:435)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:182)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_for_rows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:630)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1081)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2905)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2977)
    - locked <0x3339ad48> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement)
    - locked <0x2f8327d0> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:147)
    at com.sia.sd.db.dao.KMDatabaseDAO.insert(KMDatabaseDAO.java:125)
```

[Oracle PreparedStatement API](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/1012/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/jdbc/driver/OraclePreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you have a PreparedStatement means that you've already retrieved a connection from the pool, so no, the pool is not exhausted, and executing a PreparedStatement can't exhaust it because doing so doesn't retrieve another Connection from the pool.